# How to echo single name from multiple same name from the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble on how to display/echo single name from multiple value of (three) of the same name. My table name is `usages`.

```
id | account  | amount  |  date
1    Purchase   10000      2015-04-01
2    Repair     200000     2015-04-02
3    Purchae    30000      2015-04-03
4    Purchase   10000      2015-04-04
5    Mafanikio  20000      2015-04-04
6    Simon      20000      2015-04-04
7    Spare      10000      2015-04-04
```

This is my PHP code:

```
global $database;
$i = 1;
$seL = "SELECT * FROM usages ";
$Q =$database->query($seL);
$num = $database->query_to_num_rows($seL);
if($num !=0) {
    while ($fet =$database->fetch_array($Q)) {
        $show =$fet['account'];
        $sel2 ="SELECT * FROM usages WHERE account = '$show' GROUP BY account ";
        $Que =$database->query($sel2);
        $numR =$database->query_to_num_rows($sel2);

        if($numR ==1) {
            $arr = $database->fetch_array($Que);    
            echo "<br> ".$i++. "&nbsp;&nbsp;". $a =$arr['account'];
```

The result here is:

```
1  Purchase
2  Repair 
3  Purchase
4  Purchase
5  Mafanikio
6  Simon 
7  Spare
```

My desired answer I need like this

```
1  Purchase
2  Repair 
3  Mafanikio
4  Simon 
5  Spare
```

I don't want the same name to repeat.

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT or GROUP BY Clause ? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: I used GROUP BY as is shown on my php codes

Comment: what happens when you try this query: SELECT DISTINCT(Account) FROM Usages ?

Comment: It looks like your one `account` is misspelled `Purchae`

Comment: "WHERE account = '$show' GROUP BY account" is technically not group by since you are already specifying the account here so there is no point using GROUP BY.

Comment: when I use this "SELECT DISTINCT(Account) FROM Usages" nothing display.

Answer (score 0):

use DISTINCT

In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usages WHERE account = '$show'";
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usages ";
```

use whichever your are trying to get single name from.

Comment: When I use this  "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usages WHERE account = '$show'"; The value "Purchase" disappear but others appear

Answer (score 0):

```
global $database;
$i = 1;
$seL = "SELECT DISTINCT account FROM usages ";
$Q =$database->query($seL);
$num = $database->query_to_num_rows($seL);
if($num !=0) {
    while ($fet =$database->fetch_array($Q)) {
        $show =$fet['account'];
        $sel2 ="SELECT * FROM usages WHERE account = '$show'";
        $Que =$database->query($sel2);
        $numR =$database->query_to_num_rows($sel2);

        if($numR ==1) {
            $arr = $database->fetch_array($Que);    
            echo "<br> ".$i++. "&nbsp;&nbsp;". $a =$arr['account'];
```